# comment plugin for cake2.0

Tags: cakephp, comments, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp2.0 and want to integrate comment plugin but i got nothing .I was using commentDc plugin but its not working as my requirements.Because i am integreating my users login system with xenforo and  commentDc plugin use Auth component so its not working properly.

Please let me know is there any simple comment plugin which i can integrate and modify as my needs.

Thanks,

Comment: you could just modify the dc plugin for your needs (replacing the auth system) :)

Comment: Thanks Mark.I did the change its wokring now.But I am getting error when  i am integrating  the cakedccomment plugin with more than one controller.I have integrated the cakedccomment plugin wiht Blog its working fine now but when i trying integreate  it with banner it gives me error :-> CommentsComponent: missing view variable banner or value for primary key id of model Banner Please help me I am struggling with comment functionality form last week my project is on hold because of this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I set up comments:

Comments table fields:

- id
- parent_type, matches the model name of the parent
- parent_id
- content
- user_id, the sender

In any model that you want to be commentable, at this your associations:

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'Comment' => array(
            'className' => 'Comment', 
            'foreignKey' => 'parent_id', 
            'conditions' => array('Comment.parent_type' => 'question')
        )
    );
```

This is a view element:

```
<?php
/*
set variables:
$data : data of the parent
$type : the type of the parent
*/
if(!isset($name)) {
$name = 0;
}
foreach($data['Comment'] as $comment){
    echo '<div class="comment">'.$comment['content'].
        ' - '.$this->Html->link($comment['User']['username'],array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'view',$comment['User']['id']))
        .'</div>';
}
echo $this->Form->create(null, array('url' => '/comments/add','id'=>'qCommentForm'));
echo $this->Form->input('Comment.parent_id', array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>$data[$type]['id']));
echo $this->Form->input('Comment.parent_type', array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>$type));
echo $this->Form->textarea('Comment.content',array('div'=>'false','class'=>'small','label'=>false));
echo $this->Form->submit(__('Leave comment'),array('div'=>'false','class'=>'small'));
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Then, in the view view for your model, add this (assuming you named the element comment.ctp:

```
<?php echo $this->element('comment',array('data'=>$modelData,'type'=>'MyModel')) ?>
```